# String replace and manipluation on a group capture

Tags: javascript, regex

I was wondering if it is possible to do any javascript manipulation on a group capture from a RegEx match result (`$` sign match) using `string.replace()` method.

Basically I'm doing something like:

```
src = src.replace(/... some regexp expression .../gi,encodeURIComponent('$1'))
```

But obviously with the intention of encoding the backreference `$1` value, instead of the string `'$1'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a callback function:

```
src = src.replace(/.../gi, function(match) {
    return encodeURIComponent(match[1]);
});
```